# Angular routing from Amchart 4 MapChart to selected country

Tags: angular, amcharts4

I want to route to selected country on map.
So I defined in constructor

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone, private router: Router) {
}
```

And after that init of MapChart

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {

        this.chart = am4core.create(this.chartDom.nativeElement, am4maps.MapChart);

        this.chart.geodata = am4geodata_worldLow;

        this.chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();

        let polygonSeries = this.chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());

        polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;

        let polygonTemplate = polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template;

        polygonTemplate.events.on('hit', function (ev) {
            // get object info
            console.log(ev.target.dataItem.dataContext);
        });....
```

So I need somehow pass this.router to the body of this event function. Or what is the right way?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0t9f.png)
The only option that is working for me is  window.location.href = 'some url'. But I think it's not right way.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution. So I was need to pass 'this'. Hope it will be helpfull for someone also.

```
 polygonTemplate.events.on('hit', function (ev) {
            // get object info
            console.log(ev.target.dataItem.dataContext);
            this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F']);'
        }, this);
```